# Metric hierarchy and pages

Tags: google-analytics

Lets say I have a conversion page along the lines:

> example.com/thankyou

If I then, in Google-Analytics, create a custom report:
Metrics: Unique Visitors, Unique Pageviews and Pageviews
Dimension: page.

Then add filter "thank" I find my conversion page at the top:
Unique Visitors: 1,500, Unique Page Views: 1,700 and Pageviews: 3,000.

Does that mean that per session where a conversion took place, the average page views of the last page were 2?

We're investigating our funnel and I've used the conversion page as an example. Sure we'd expect that some folk may refresh the conversion page after 30 minutes but this appears like each person is seeing that page twice?﻿

Comment: Doug, are you using segments (above the charts) or filters (above the report table)?

Comment: @PetrHavlík not in this instance but I often do. Why? What was your line of thinking?

Comment: I was referring to your "Then add filter "thank" I find my conversion page". There is a difference between the totals if you use Filter OR Segment...

Comment: @PetrHavlík I tried adding a custom segment but same results. It appears as though our conversion page is being viewed almost twice by each visitor

Comment: any chance you could share a screenshot? also, what about redirects etc.?